# Typescript Alias Instance of Generalized Class

Tags: typescript, alias

I'm currently trying to alias a generalized class. I'm using the typescript-collections package and want to do some renaming.

```
class Bar<T> {}
class Foo = Bar<X>;
```

How would I go about doing the second line?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by the 2nd line? How would you then use `Foo`?

Comment: I plan to just replace `Bar<T>` with `Foo` everywhere I see it. `Bar<T>` is a very long name that comes from the typescript-collections package and `Foo` is a much more meaningful name.

Comment: you can just do type Foo = Bar<number>; but I'm not sure what purpose that would serve. Besides a type alias in some places.. you can't use the type to create new objects for example, only use it as a type alias.

Comment: Ok, then is there some way to alias the class? I want to be able to forget about `Bar<T>` and just use `Foo` in it's place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is to alias `Bar<X>` in type annotations/hints in other places (eg. `function blah(foo: Bar<X>)`) you can use the following statement:

```
type Foo = Bar<X>;
```

Note that you still can't do `new Foo()`, the `type` statement only contributes to the "types" portion of TypeScript, and not to the "values" portion (like a class does).

If you want an actual class, a simple and effective solution would be to extend the original `Bar<X>` class like so:

```
class Foo extends Bar<X> {}
```

I, personally, don't particularly like this solution though, as it makes your code less clear.

Comment: Is there some way to do the second part though, and not just get the type information?

Comment: Edited. Again, I don't particularly like this solution. OO inheritance shouldn't be used for aliasing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a type alias as @toskv suggested:

```
type Foo = Bar<X>;
```

Then you can use it as a type:

```
let foo: Foo = new Bar<X>();
```

If you'll have a constructor that receives an instance of `X` then the compiler will infer the type:

```
class Bar<T> {
    constructor(x: X) { }
}

let foo: Foo = new Bar();
```

If you want a new class which is bound to a specific generic constraint then you'll need to do something like:

```
class Foo extends Bar<X> { ... }

let foo = new Foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit `Foo` from `Bar<X>` to make a class with the `X` type parameter predefined:

```
class Foo extends Bar<X> {}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a type alias then you can use type to create it this way:

```
type Foo = Bar<X>;
```

With this you will be able to do things like:

```
let x: Foo;
```

But not:

```
let x= new Foo();
```

Another solution would be to just extend Bar and make an empty class. It's not really how you're supposed to use the class hierarchies but it does what you need.

```
class Foos extends Bar<number> { }
```